# What's the story behind the intro of GITS:SAC soundtrack 08 - Velveteen borrowing a sample from Blade Runner (1982)?

Tags: music, ghost-in-the-shell-sac

I just rewatched the original Blade Runner and noticed that in one of the scenes where the police sirens are heard (starts roughly at 01:26:30) is the exact same sound as the sirens from the track 08 - Velveteen of GITS:SAC soundtrack.

It's pretty much common knowledge that Ghost in the Shell universe and aesthetic was inspired in a large part by the previous works in sci-fi genre, Blade Runner especially. Is there any trivia about this specific sample being included into the track? As far as I know, clearing legal right for using audio clips from copyrighted works (like songs and movies) takes a lot of work. Was there any notable publicity about this?

Here's a video of the moment in the movie matched up with the track:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58pBi1PfoEA

Comment: Without knowing if the sample is originated from *Blade Runner*, what if both *Blade Runner* and *GitS* use the same sample from somewhere? (can't watch the YouTube video at the moment)

Comment: didn't think of that :p